# .htaccess regex redirect avoid by file type

Tags: .htaccess, apache2

I have two URL conditions and I wanted to redirect them like this:

```
    https://www.example.com/feeds/4aceXy to https://www.example.com/direct_feed/4aceXy
```

Now the problem is, I am also using the URL for an older link like this one:

```
https://wwww.example.com/feeds/5bdb39711b41d479273e678a6f356603d7109ffc.xml
```

I wanted to avoid redirect with `.xml` extension here is my current redirect:

```
RewriteRule feeds/(.*)?$ https://wwww.example.com/direct_feed/$1 [QSA,L]
```

It works fine but I don't want to redirect it with `.xml` based URL.

My question is - is there a condition that can help me to avoid the rewrite if a parameter contains `.xml` in regX `(.*)?$`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a negative lookbehind:

```
RewriteRule feeds/(.*)?(?<!\.xml)$ https://wwww.example.com/direct_feed/$1 [QSA,L]
```